# PHP image generator fails for none of the typical reasons

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, gd, mime-types

I have a PHP file which generates an image of a specified size for testing. I guess the browser thinks the script's output would be text/html. So far I have installed php5-gd and saved my php file as UTF-8 without BOM, yet I still have the issue. Using readfile() to send an existing image to the browser works as it should.

My PHP image generator:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$im = null;
$width = 400;
$height = 300;
if (isset($_GET['w']) && isset($_GET['h'])) {
    if (is_numeric($_GET['w']) && is_numeric($_GET['h'])) {
        $width = $_GET['w'];
        $height = $_GET['h'];
    }
}
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
imagestring($im, 3, 5, 5,  'TEST IMAGE', $orange);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Example code from PHP.net which also doesn't work:

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
```

Working readfile() method:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('./site_top/1.jpg');
```

UPDATE: PEBKAC Error.
When installing gd I saw that the Apache server restarted during the process, so I didn't think to restart it myself. It turned out I needed to restart Apache a second time in order for the installation to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and pasted your code, works fine, as noted on the PHP page of the [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function:

> **Note:** JPEG support is only available if PHP was compiled against
>   GD-1.8 or later.

Make sure your PHP has at least GD-1.8.

Image shown from your code below:

[image: Working Image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped me out. I tried displaying the gd_info array in the command line and in a browser, and noticed that the browser didn't display anything whereas the terminal showed the array. After that I restarted Apache and my problem was solved.